# SilverStripe 4 custom error page not shown

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In my last project on SS 4, I'm trying to create my usual custom error pages - with same approach used on v. 3:

- Creating `ErrorPage.ss` inside `/themes/mysite/templates/Layout`;
- Including `$Content` inside template;

After a successful `/dev/build?flush=all` I don't see any content, neither right template (I see the default `Page.ss` one instead).

In back-end there are error pages saved and published. In `/assets/` there are the static ones too.

Maybe the procedure is changed in this new version? Any advice?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ErrorPage.ss folder structure needs to match the core PHP class's namespace (`SilverStripe\ErrorPage\ErrorPage`), i.e. `themes/mytheme/templates/SilverStripe/ErrorPage/Layout/ErrorPage.ss`

Answer (score 1):

For Silverstripe 4 ErrorPage.

To display the ErrorPage you need to match the namespace of ErrorPage into your template by adding this into your app folder. E.g.`template/SilverStripe/ErrorPage/ErrorPage.ss`

Don't forget to dev/build?flush afterwards